Using powershell, how can I extract the OU path for a computer currently in AD?
I've managed to isolate the Distinguished Name, but I want to get rid of the Common Name part and only have the OU path. The length of the computer name will change depending on the pc, so I want to be able to only keep everything listed after the first comma (if that makes sense). It should work regardless if the PC name is 8 characters or 12 characters. This is what I have so far.
$testingThis = Get-ADComputer -Identity "ComputerExample" -Properties DistinguishedName | Select-Object -ExpandProperty DistinguishedName

Write-Output $testingThis

This is the output:
CN=example,OU=example,OU=example,OU=example,DC=madeup,DC=madeup,DC=madeup,DC=madeup


If I understand you correctly, you want to get only the OU where the machine is located.
You can do this:
$dn = $testingThis -split ',', 2
$dn = $dn[1]
$dn

or use an function to do that
    function Get-ComputerOU {
    param (
        [string]$ComputerName
    )

    # Get the Distinguished Name (DN) of the computer from Active Directory
    $Computer = Get-ADComputer -Identity $ComputerName -Properties DistinguishedName

    # Check if the computer was found
    if ($Computer -ne $null) {
        # Split the DN and return only the OU part
        $OUPath = ($Computer.DistinguishedName -split ',', 2)[1]
        return $OUPath
    } else {
        Write-Output "Computer not found."
    }
}

# Example usage
Get-ComputerOU "Computername"


While this will typically work, it isn't robust; e.g., it fails with a DN such as 'CN=Martin Luther King\, Jr.,OU=Ministry,DC=example,DC=org' That is, your solution doesn't recognize value-internal , characters, which must be escaped as \,, as such.

That said, you could borrow part of the regex from Santiago's answer to fix this problem: ($testingThis -split '(?<!\\),', 2)[1]

Or, one could use the name-parsing COM object that already exists, and then one doesn't need to worry about the complexity of regex parsing for distinguished names.

@Bill_Stewart, using a dedicated API is always preferable, and I up-voted your answer for that, but, pragmatically speaking, a (robust) regex solution is much more concise in this case, given the hoops you have to jump through to access that API.

Interesting feedback, but I'm going to have to disagree that a regex is a preferable way to parse distinguished names, regardless of how concise.

@Bill_Stewart, it's not the generally preferable way, but it is in the case at hand, purely for pragmatic reasons. The difficulties around accessing the API referenced in your answer also make it non-obvious how to adapt your solution to other use cases.

Again, appreciate the feedback! I disagree, though. I think the API is worth learning and not difficult to adapt.

You can use -replace operator with a regex pattern ^CN=.+?(?<!\\),. As aside, DistinguishedName is a default attribute, there is no need for -Properties DistinguishedName.
$testingThis = Get-ADComputer -Identity 'ComputerExample'
$testingThis.DistinguishedName -replace '^CN=.+?(?<!\\),'


^ asserts position at start of a line

CN= matches the characters CN= literally

. matches any character (except for line terminators)

+? matches the previous token between one and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy)

Negative Lookbehind (?<!\\)

Assert that the Regex below does not match


\\ matches the character \


, matches the character ,



Thanks for this. What is being replaced? I'm confused about that part

@skysthelimit91 if you click on the link for the regex pattern you will get an explanation about the pattern but essentially everything from the beginning of the string including the first comma when that comma is not preceded by a backslash

I recommend using the IADsPathname interface (Pathname COM object) rather than string parsing and regexes because it's designed for this purpose. The trick in using it in PowerShell is that it lacks a type library, so the syntax for calling the object's methods is a bit "ugly" unless we write a helper function.
For example:
# Pathname COM object (implements IADsPathname interface but lacks typelib)
$ADS_SETTYPE_DN = 4
$ADS_FORMAT_X500_PARENT = 8
$Pathname = New-Object -ComObject "Pathname" -ErrorAction Stop

# Invokes a method for a COM object that lacks a typelib
function Invoke-Method {
  param(
    [__ComObject]
    $object,

    [String]
    $method,

    $params
  )
  $result = $object.GetType().InvokeMember($method,"InvokeMethod",$null,$object,$params)
  if ( $null -ne $result ) {
    $result
  }
}

$DN = "CN=COMPUTER1,OU=Computers,DC=fabrikam,DC=local"

# Sets the distinguished name
Invoke-Method $Pathname "Set" @($DN,$ADS_SETTYPE_DN)
# Retrieves the parent; e.g. "OU=Computers,DC=fabrikam,DC=local"
Invoke-Method $Pathname "Retrieve" $ADS_FORMAT_X500_PARENT

